# When running any GUI command over SSH: cannot open display: localhost:11.0

Tags: server, ssh, x11-forwarding

**Host:** Kubuntu

**Client:** Windows 10 with Linux subsystem

**Goal:**
I want to be able to ssh into my host machine and export the display for GUIs, such as kwrite or gedit.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to SSH from one machine to another on the same network. The error is as follows when running any GUI command (kwrite, gedit, etc):

```
/tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:5453): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
```

**Things I've tried:**

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
rm ~/.Xauthority # followed by re-login to regenerate
```

Something that seems suspicious... there is no file `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, however, there IS a file called `/tmp/.X11-unix/X1`

Comment: Try `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0`

Comment: Have you actually started an X server (`xming`, or via `cygwin` for example) on the Windows host?

Comment: steeldriver, I do have xming running. On the windows client, I can open GUI programs (gedit, etc,.) just fine. I cannot open GUI programs when shelling into the host machine.

Comment: FireFaced, tried your solution and unfortunately the problem persists.